# Questions about the center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help with this advanced algebra problem.

> Let $G$ be a group.  We call the set  $C(G)= \{a \in G : ab=ba, \forall b \in G\}$ the center of $G$. 
>    Prove that:
>
> (a)    $C(G)$ is normal subgroup of $G$.
>
> (b)   $C(G)=G$ if and only if $G$ is abelian group.
>
> (c)   If $a$ is the only element  in $G$, then $a\in C(G)$.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This question doesn't show much effort on the part of the questioner to solve the problem

Comment: It is not a homework, but I need solution to it. I don't see a problem if anyone is willing to help me.

Comment: I agree this looks like homework and does not show much effort.

Comment: The centre is usually denoted by $Z(G)$, the $Z$ standing for zentrum (which is the German for centre - pre-war maths was all German...)

Comment: I am curious: since this is not homework, in exactly what kind of context did such a sequence of problems arise for you? The first part is a routine result that is in most abstract algebra books (comparable to discussions of $dy/dx = ay$ in calculus books), and part c seems very strange as anything *other* than homework;  I can't imagine how else part c could be a task.

Comment: @KCd: In fairness, they could just be problems from a book (and so not homework per se) However, the "*need*" a solution is intriguing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Let $g \in G$, suppose $a \in C(G)$, $gag^{-1} = agg^{-1} = a$.

(b) If $G = C(G)$, then $a \in G$ implies $a \in C(G)$ so for any $b \in G$, $ab = ba$. Suppose $G$ is abelian, then clearly $ab = ba$ for all $a$.

(c) If $a$ is the only only element of $G$, then $a$ must be the identity. Clearly the identity element is in the center.

Comment: Fixed it, but does it really matter.

Comment: You should also prove that it is a subgroup...

Answer (score 8):

**Hints**

1. $xax^{-1}=a$ for $a\in C(G)$.
2. If $b\in G\setminus C(G)$. Do you have $x b=bx$ for each $x\in G$?
3. What is your favorite group with one element?

Answer (score 1):

- If $C(G)$ is the subgroup of elements that commute in $G$, don't they satisfy the axioms for a normal subgroup?
- In an abelian group, all the elements commute.
- If $a\in C(G)$, it commutes with all the other elements.  If it is the only element, does it commute with all the "other" elements?

Comment: How can I prove the third statement if a is the only element of second order in the group?

Comment: If $a$ is the only element of a group, then $a$ is the identity element $a=1$.  Clearly, the identity commutes with all other elements, $1\in G, 1.b=b.1 \forall b\in G$

Comment: It's clear. Thank you. Is the same statement true, if a is the only element of *second order* in the group?

Comment: Yes.  if $a^2=1$, then obviously $1.a=a.1$ and $a*a=1=a*a$, the element commutes with itself.

Comment: @Adam: Use `*text*` for italics, not math mode - I have corrected your comment above. [See here for more formatting commands](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

@Adam, first of all do not write $C(G)$ but $Z(G)$ for the center. This is common in group theory. Secondly, what you mean is if $a$ is the only element of *order 2* (and not "second order"). 
If that is the case then observe that for every element $g \in G$, the conjugate $g^{-1}ag$ also has order 2. Hence $a = g^{-1}ag$ for all $g \in G$, that is $a \in Z(G)$.